# Confusion with VS 2017 dotnet-sdk-2.1.4 and .NET Core 2.0.6 .NET Core SDK 2.1.101

Tags: visual-studio-2017, .net-core, .net-core-2.0

I want to target latest .Net Core 2.0.6 to build console app in Visual Studio 2017, **the issue is that latest VS .Net Core SDK currently** as per:
https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/visual-studio-sdks
is
**dotnet-sdk-2.1.4**-windows-x64-installer, released January 9, 2018 with .Net Core 2.0.5
https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/release-notes/2.0/2.0.5.md

**What should I do to target .Net Core 2.0.6 shipped with .NET Core SDK 2.1.101?**, released March 13, 2018
https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/release-notes/2.0/2.0.6.md

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, by googling "dotnet-sdk-2.1.101-windows-x64-installer"

I found:
https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/dotnet-core/sdk-2.1.101
Which contains:
https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/thank-you/dotnet-sdk-2.1.101-windows-x64-installer

So MS need to update .Net Core SDK link in below link ASAP!
https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/visual-studio-sdks

After installtion I still can't see any mention for 2.0.6 within VS

[image: VS screenshot]

But in command-line latest version seems active!

[image]